# Check if Fragment exists in Fragment TabHost Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity A, which implements Fragment Tab Host with 2 Tabs. The first tab is a List View and the second Tab has same data in an Expandable List View. Below is the code snippet from my Fragment activity:

```
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),
    R.layout.activity_list);

mTabHost.addTab(
      mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("List"),
      ListFragment.class, null);
mTabHost.addTab(
      mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("ExList"),
      ExpandableListFragment.class, arg2);
```

Now issue is if I call the activity again its creating Fragments again. I need to check if fragment already exists it need not add new one. I tried below stuff but that isn't working

```
 Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("List");
        if (f!=null && f instanceof ListFragment){
            Log.i("ListActivity","Already Created");
        }
```

For the above code I am getting null for Fragment f when activity is called again. Read some similar posts but nothing seem to be working. Please advise how can I make sure that Fragments are not created again when ListActivity is called. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it should matter to keep an instance of a fragment alive in your tabactivity. If your activity is not destroyed, so won't your fragments be. But if your activity is destroyed, and the fragments too, it's not a big problem that they are recreated, as the old instance will soon be cleaned up by the garbage collector. I don't understand why you'd want to control this behavior. Just initialize your tabbar in the `onCreate()` of your activity, destroy it in the `onDestroy()` and let the android lifecycle do it's job.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I need this as I refresh my list view with new data from server on list item click. Also when I get notification from server, I have to refresh list in first Tab. So I call this activity from Intent Service. Since it recreates new fragment, on back button press I get the older fragment too.